# Create bitmap file and send it to a client

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-2016

I need to create a bitmap file with below specification and send it to client using BizTalk

```
BIT     NAME                          Attribute     Length 
-       Msg Type                        n               4 
-       Bit map                         b               64 
1       Bit map, Extended               b               64 
2       UniqueID                        n              …19 
7   Transmission Date and Time          n               10
```

This is the first time I am working with bitmap fields.. Can someone provide me the example of the records as per the above bitmap fields specification.

And how do we send the record using biztalk..like which piepline should we use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a positional flat file.

So create a positional flat file schema and use a flatfile pipeline.